# mySQL JOIN statements not returning what I wanted

Tags: sql, mysql, join, mysql-error-1064

I want to display a "FULL JOIN" of two tables, but using an intermediary with foreign keys to create the matches.

This should show a list of all employees with the projects they are working on, and show any employees without projects, or projects without employees.

The problem with this query is that the second, "RIGHT JOIN" overrides the first "LEFT JOIN". All my attempts at a "FULL JOIN" the second time have failed. (1064 syntax error, real descriptive)

```
SELECT EMP_LNAME, EMP_FNAME, Project.PROJ_NAME
FROM Employee1
LEFT JOIN Assignment ON Employee1.EMP_CODE = Assignment.EMP_CODE
FULL JOIN Project ON Assignment.PROJ_CODE = Project.PROJ_CODE
ORDER BY Employee1.EMP_LNAME /* Syntax error */
```

The second type I tried

```
SELECT EMP_LNAME, EMP_FNAME, Project.PROJ_NAME
FROM Employee1
LEFT JOIN Assignment ON Employee1.EMP_CODE = Assignment.EMP_CODE
RIGHT JOIN Project ON Assignment.PROJ_CODE = Project.PROJ_CODE
ORDER BY Employee1.EMP_LNAME /* Right join overwrites original left join */
```

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make it clear:

Table Employee1 has the names and ids of the employees. 
Table Projects has the names and ids of the projects. 
Table Assignment uses the foreign keys to assign employees to projects. 

I want to do a "FULL JOIN" on the Employee1 and Project tables, but have to use the Assignment table as an intermediary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a FULL OUTER JOIN in MySQL you need to first perform a LEFT JOIN and then a RIGHT JOIN and UNION ALL the results (or instead of a RIGHT JOIN reverse the tables and use another LEFT JOIN). But one thing to be careful of is that in the second join you need to discard rows for which the join succeeds so that you don't get duplicates in the result.

```
SELECT EMP_LNAME, EMP_FNAME, Project.PROJ_NAME
FROM Employee1
LEFT JOIN Assignment ON Employee1.EMP_CODE = Assignment.EMP_CODE
LEFT JOIN Project ON Assignment.PROJ_CODE = Project.PROJ_CODE
UNION ALL
SELECT EMP_LNAME, EMP_FNAME, Project.PROJ_NAME
FROM Project
LEFT JOIN Assignment ON Assignment.PROJ_CODE = Project.PROJ_CODE
LEFT JOIN Employee1 ON Employee1.EMP_CODE = Assignment.EMP_CODE
WHERE Employee1.ID IS NULL
ORDER BY EMP_LNAME
```

I'm assuming here that your `Employee1` table has a field call ID that is not nullable.

Comment: Sorry, the /* Duplicate */ indicates that's the same as the original, what exactly do you mean different aliases? LEFT JOIN Assignment AS temp?

Comment: Valid criticism, but not an answer to the question of how to get the desired output.

Comment: That's interesting, but now the employees with multiple projects are showing up multiple times (Thanks to the union?) and the project without an assigned employee doesn't show up. Making the second join in the first select a "RIGHT JOIN" fixed the problem with the project not showing up though.

Comment: @J V: If an employee has multiple projects and you only are allowed to return one row, which project do you want associated with that employee? Will any project do or are you looking for some specific one?

Comment: @Mark: I didn't say I only wanted one row, it's just that it was giving twice the amount of rows it should have. Never mind, latest edit works, but I'm wondering if there isn't a more efficient way to do this. I will browse the Drupal Views SQL to get some ideas.

Comment: @J V: OK sorry, I misunderstood. I had a NOT in my query that shouldn't have been there - removing it fixed it. :) - *But one thing to be careful of is that in the second join you need to discard rows for which the join* **succeeds** (I was removing the rows where the join *failed*).

Comment: Right. Thanks! I still wish there were a way to do this with a single select statement, it would probably perform better.

Comment: @J V: Maybe one day MySQL will implement FULL OUTER JOIN. Keep your eye on this bug: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=18003 (but it has still not implemented 4 years after the feature was requested, so don't hold your breath).

Comment: Well with the way oracle is scaring off open source devs mysql will probably speed up development as soon as someone makes an "Open database foundation" :)

Answer (score 2):

[MySQL doesn't support "FULL" in it's JOIN syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html), what you're after specifically is called a [FULL OUTER JOIN](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

This is [one of the means to get the output you desire](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/05/26/how-to-write-full-outer-join-in-mysql/):

```
    SELECT e.emp_lname,
           e.emp_fname,
           p.project_name
      FROM EMPLOYEE e
 LEFT JOIN ASSIGNMENT a ON a.emp_code = e.emp_code
      JOIN PROJECT p ON p.proj_code = a.proj_code
UNION
   SELECT e.emp_lname,
           e.emp_fname,
           p.project_name
      FROM EMPLOYEE e
RIGHT JOIN ASSIGNMENT a ON a.emp_code = e.emp_code
      JOIN PROJECT p ON p.proj_code = a.proj_code
ORDER BY emp_lname
```